# Moving, resizing and scaling UIView with touch gestures

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I have to write some code for a UIView that will contain a set of markers. I must be able to grab each, move it, resize it and rotate it.

It seems like something rather generic, I wonder if any one knows of a library that does just that.

Thanks

EDIT: Look at the comments of Michail Grebionkin for the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to use `UIScrollView` instead of `UIView`. Scroll view already have methods for moving and scaling content. The only thing you'll need to implement is rotating content.

Comment: No I don't think this will do since I need to have several markers in the container view.

Comment: In this case I propose to use gesture recognizers.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this one. I read it quickly I think it will do.

Answer (score 1):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.03 animations:^{
                view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2);
            }];
```

It will resize ur content If u want to scale u can use scrollviews for  rotating which type of rotation can u describe ur question briefly...